# Refactoring code that uses new operator to be more testable

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd, factory-pattern

I have the following code and am trying to unit test it:


`public override IRenderable GetRenderable()

{

    var val = SomeCalculationUsingClassMemberVariables();

    return new EquationRenderable(val);

}`

It seems like I want to use a factory here so I can separate the creation of the IRenderable from this class.  The problem is that I have many of these classes that create different IRenderables that are constructed in different ways, so I would need to implement a new factory method for each one.  What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: What about decoupling the creation and usage... its a bit tricky since you haven'r provided much code, but instead of letting your class(es) that needs a IRenderable object create it themselves you pass such an object to it. In that way you can instantiate the class in question, pass some fake IRenderable object to it and test whatever methods you need tested.

Comment: The GetRenderable function basically returns a string version of the class it's called on - so it's almost like serializing the object.  I'm not sure how this could be pulled out of the object that it's in, since the Renderable is created based on the member variables. By the way, thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

First of all, feeling tempted to use AbstractFactories everywhere smells a bit as DI container is not used the "right" way or design could be improved.

But sometimes I've also come across this problem. I see following:

1. using AbstractFactory/Factory and Inject it. For C# you have to advantage that you can pass delegates, acting as interface for the creation of instance.
2. 'new' is OK, simply test the output of 'new'.
3. Stub the call of 'new' inside extracted method (hacky!!)

Injection got mentioned already so I won't repeat. I am more into Java so please excuse some syntax errors.

## Test the output of 'new'

I often use this, if the 'new' created instances are domain-objects and not services. Because it is returned directly in method I can test the direct output with my test.

```
Prod-Code:
...
public override IRenderable GetRenderable()
{
  var val = SomeCalculationUsingClassMemberVariables();
  return new EquationRenderable(val);
} 

Test Case:
...
[Test]
public void test_new()
{
  SUT sut = ...;
  IRenderable r = sut.GetRenderable();
  assertTrue(r instanceof EquationRenderable);
}
```

## Stub the call of 'new' itself

Testing direct output from above is only possible if you somehow get it as return value. Things get more complicated if the "sideeffect" of your code are indirect outputs, which you can't sense directly by the return value. If so I often extract-method of the new-creation and then have it under control in my test. This is yucky and I more use it to go safe with my test and start more refactoring later (DI and factories). I sometimes do this in legacy code where services are created with 'new' directly and refactoring to DI is too risky without tests.

```
Prod-Code:
...
public override IRenderable GetRenderable()
{
  var val = SomeCalculationUsingClassMemberVariables();
  return createEquationRenderable();
} 

public IRenderable createEquationRenderable() 
{
   return new EquationRenderable(val);
}


Test Case:
...

class Stubbed : SUT 
{
   boolean called = false;

   public override EquationRenderable createEquationRenderable() 
   {
      called=true;
      return MyMock();
   }
}

[Test]
public void test_new()
{
  Stubbed sut = new Stubbed();
  sut.GetRenderable();
  assertTrue(sut.called);
  // do further stuff on MyMock
}
```

I know, the example is overkill and a bit senseless, it is just for describing the idea. I am sure above could be shortcutted with mocking-frameworks for C#. Anyway testing the return-value direct output is more trivial and better approach here.

Maybe you have a more detailed example?

Comment: Right now all I'm testing is that the return type is correct, like in your first example. The problem is that most of the logic is in calculating the parameter that is passed into the created object, and a bug in there won't be caught. I'm not totally against your second idea, but it seems a little hacky to be mocking what I'm testing. Like you mentioned, I also get the feeling that the design could be improved, but I'm having trouble seeing how to fix it.

Comment: I can also test that values on the return type are correct, but then I'm testing the implementation of that type as well, and if that changes, it will break tests in different areas.

Comment: For now, I think I'm just going to make the property for the passed in parameter public (I think my API will need that in the future anyway), so I can just test against that public property on my returned object. I'm going to continue to see what I can do to improve the design though. I really appreciate your detailed response!

Comment: no problem :) for unit testing and tackling codebases I can really recommend books http://tinyurl.com/35uog58 (xUnit-Test Patterns) and http://tinyurl.com/398ln4n (Working effectively with Legacy Code)

Answer (score 1):

depending on the uniformity of your concrete IRenderable constructors you can use the following pattern for factory creating

```
public IRenderable CreateInstance<T>(object calculation) where T : IRenderable 
{
   Activator.CreateInstance<T>(new[] { calculation });
}
```

or if you have many different constructors you can use the params keyword to pass arbitrary amounts of arguments

```
public IRenderable CreateInstance<T>(params object[] args) where T : IRenderable 
{
   Activator.CreateInstance<T>(args);
}
```

To be able to do some kind of runtime check of the arguments you use this code before calling the Activator.CreateInstance

```
var types = args.Select(o => o.GetType()).ToArray();

var c = typeof(T).GetConstructor(types);
if (c == null)
{
   throw new InvalidOperationException("No matched constructor")
}
```

Comment: I considered this approach as well, but it seems like it will cause harder to find runtime errors if the wrong parameters are passed in.  Plus there will be no way for the client to know what parameters are required to create a certain instance, because the concrete constructors are not very uniform at all.  Maybe I'm just asking for too much here.

Comment: When the client calls the CreateInstance method they have to pass a type and at that point has knowledge of the implementation (rtfm :)). Its true that you can't do compiler checking on the arguments, but that is not the same as the client not being able to read in the docs what arguments to pass. Im tempted to say that unless you constrain yourself in what constructors are allowed in your IRenderable classes, there is no way to do compiler checking of arguments in a factory pattern like this.

Comment: I've added a small snippet so a runtime error witch invalid arguments maybe makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Alright, that's pretty much where I ended up as well.  Is a factory pattern generally used in this kind of scenario, where its only purpose is to increase testability?

Comment: yes, Factory Pattern or Dependency Injection is what you would be going for to make things more plug- and testable. And i can rest assure you that DI would go for the same approach with matching arguments to the right constructor at runtime, so no help there by switching to DI.

Comment: IMHO, it's overkill just to ensure testing one object in isolation though. Is the idea to only have new operators inside factory classes? There's got to be a better way to test methods that create objects. I'm already using DI for class-level dependencies, and that's working great.

Answer (score 0):

A better way may be to simply unit test the code *as is* instead of refactoring it. Technically, this can be done by using a suitable mocking tool such as TypeMock Isolator or Microsoft Moles (there is a third one which I don't remember now).